# Add additional css class name in react app

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm using bulma css in my react application. And I have some additional css in my css module file to set image size.

Additionally I want to use css classes from bulma like `my-2 mr-4` in my main wrapping div.

How do I add these classes to the main wrapping div ?

```js
import React from "react";

import logoimg from "../../assets/images/logo.svg";
import classes from "./Logo.module.scss";

const logo = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className={classes.Logo}>
      <a href="/">
        <img src={logoimg} />
        <p>Resume Builder</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  );
};

export default logo;
```

```css
.Logo a img {
  width: 80px;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.Logo a {
  text-align: center;
}

.Logo a p {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #434343;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use classnames npm mudule. classnames is conditionally joining classNames together.install this mudule with

```
npm install classnames --save
```

or

```
yarn add classnames
```

and use for example :

```
import React from "react";
import cs from "classnames";

import logoimg from "../../assets/images/logo.svg";
import classes from "./Logo.module.scss";

const logo = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className={cs(classes.Logo, 'my-2', 'mr-4' )}>
      <a href="/">
        <img src={logoimg} />
        <p>Resume Builder</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  );
};

export default logo;
```

**also you can use this code without any module**

```
className={`${classes.Logo} my-2 mr-4`}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass more classes into `className` using template literal strings. Here's an example passing in the `my-2` and `mr-4` you wanted to add:

```
import React from "react";

import logoimg from "../../assets/images/logo.svg";
import classes from "./Logo.module.scss";

const logo = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className={`${classes.Logo} my-2 mr-4`}>
      <a href="/">
       <img src={logoimg} />
        <p>Resume Builder</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  );
};

export default logo;
```

Answer (score 0):

All that `classes.Logo` does is return a string corresponding to the css class name for Logo which they have made unique(for scoping purposes), so you can just append it to a pre existing string, either by defining string in a variable or by doing it inline

Eg:

```
const logo = (props) => {
let logoClass = 'my-2 mr-4 ' + classes.Logo;
  return (
    <div className={logoClass}>
      <a href="/">
        <img src={logoimg} />
        <p>Resume Builder</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Or doing it inline like `<div className={'my-2 mr-4 ' + classes.Logo}>`

P.S would recommend first approach because you can change the string conditionally. Oh, and make sure that the classes are space seperated in the string.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it implmented you need to install the [Bulma npm package](https://bulma.io/documentation/overview/start/). Then in the .scss file you are importing in your React code (in your case the logo functional component file) you need to import whatever Bulma CSS you want to use from the `node_modules` folder for example your `Logo.module.scss` could contain something like this:

```css
// Import only what you need from Bulma
@import "../../../node_modules/bulma/sass/utilities/_all.sass";
@import "../../../node_modules/bulma/sass/base/_all.sass";
@import "../../../node_modules/bulma/sass/elements/button.sass";
@import "../../../node_modules/bulma/sass/elements/container.sass";
@import "../../../node_modules/bulma/sass/elements/title.sass";
@import "../../../node_modules/bulma/sass/form/_all.sass";
@import "../../../node_modules/bulma/sass/components/navbar.sass";
@import "../../../node_modules/bulma/sass/layout/hero.sass";
@import "../../../node_modules/bulma/sass/layout/section.sass";
```

Finally include the class names you want to use by appending them to the `logoClasses` string and setting them as the value (delimited by a space) for the `className` attribute in your wrapping div:

```
const logo = (props) => {
let logoClass = 'my-2 mr-4 ' + classes.Logo;
  return (
    <div className={logoClass}>
      <a href="/">
        <img src={logoimg} />
        <p>Resume Builder</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  );
};
```